# Isometric Projection and Culling

Tags: javascript, algorithm, computational-geometry, graphics, canvas

I'm working on a small isometric drawing system in JavaScript. After much help from the Gamedev section, reading old questions, I've got something working. However, it's still a little hacky. I need to fix the culling to be more straightforward and it still isn't quite getting edge tiles down correctly.

I want to improve the code to ensure that:

1. The "center" tile is actually centered in the drawing area.
2. The are always enough edge tiles.
3. The code is straight-forward

[Link to live Codepen.](http://codepen.io/noxabellus/pen/EDbvr?editors=001)

Here is the camera drawing function:

```
function cameraDraw(position)
{
  var cen = {
        a: position.x + position.y,
        b: position.x - position.y
      },
      max = { //Use testSize instead of canvas size so we can see overdraw
        a: Math.floor(testSize.y/(terrainImg.width/2))+1, //Adding +1 to each for better edging?? Is this normal?
        b: Math.floor(testSize.x/terrainImg.width)+1
      },
      startPos = {
        x: (((cen.a - max.a) + (cen.b - max.b))/2),
        y: (((cen.a - max.a) - (cen.b - max.b))/2)
      },
      offset = { //Subtract 100 to show overdraw
        x: (startPos.x - startPos.y) * (terrainImg.width/2) + terrainImg.width/2 + terrainImg.width/4 - 100, //+terrainImg widths for better placement
        y: (startPos.x + startPos.y) * (terrainImg.width/4) + terrainImg.width/4 - 100
      };

  for(var a = cen.a - max.a; a < cen.a + max.a; a++)
  {
    for(var b = cen.b - max.b; b < cen.b + max.b+1/*I add +1 here to take care of edge issue on the bottom...Should I have to do that, if I'd done it right, above?*/; b++)
    {
      if ((b&1) != (a&1))
        continue; 

      var x = (a+b)/2,
          y = (a-b)/2;

      world[x][y].draw(offset, position);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the tile .draw function:

```
this.draw = function(offset, p)
{
  var drawPos = {
    x: (X-Y)*(terrainImg.width/2) - offset.x,
    y: (X+Y)*(terrainImg.width/4) - offset.y
  };

  if(X == p.x && Y == p.y)
    drawPos.y -= 15;

  ctx.drawImage(terrainImg, drawPos.x, drawPos.y);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

This code is pretty well written, although there are a few things that really bug me a little.

First off, inline comments, like the one you've positioned inside that `for` loop, are eyesores to look at. Preferably, comments should stay on their own separate lines.

Secondly, your naming could be improved. For example, what does the variable `cen` do? It's name doesn't give any hint as to what it does, nor do it's contained items, `a` and `b`. Variable names should be descriptive, and describe the purpose of a variable, all while not being too long, or too short.

Finally, use braces around your `if` statements. Have you ever heard of the *"`goto fail`"* bug? That's what happened in a bug with Apple SSL. The error, in question, looked something like this:

```
if ((err = SSLHashSHA1.update(&hashCtx, &signedParams)) != 0)
    goto fail;
    goto fail;  /* MISTAKE! THIS LINE SHOULD NOT BE HERE */
```

Just use braces. They'll prevent all sorts of mistakes from occurring, and they'll make things look clearer overall as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is written well, however parts could be improved:

1. Instead of having the comma on the same line as the variable it proceeds, put it on the next line:

> ```
> var cen = {
>     a: position.x + position.y,
>     b: position.x - position.y
>   },
> ```

into:

```
var cen = {
      a: position.x + position.y
    , b: position.x - position.y
  },
```

That way you can comment out the line easier.

2. You ought to put whitespace between your operators, for readability purposes.

> ```
> Math.floor(testSize.y/(terrainImg.width/2))+1
> ```

3. Please don't put comments inside your for statement, the line before or after is the place for those:

> ```
> for(var b = cen.b - max.b; b < cen.b + max.b+1/*I add +1 here to take care of edge issue on the bottom...Should I have to do that, if I'd done it right, above?*/; b++)
> ```

4. Make sure you include brackets in your `if` statements, because as @EthanBierlein pointed out, funny business (*serious bugs*) can happen if you mess them up.

> ```
> if ((b&1) != (a&1))
>     continue;
> ```

---

Your code could use more explaining as to what everything does, whether line-by-line explanation or per function.
The comma thing and whitespace is probably the thing I can see the most that could be improved.
Other than that, your code looks really nice and tidy, good work!